# How can we call a stored procedure from xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to call a stored procedure from xslt. Has someone implemented this earlier. If so please do share it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe your problem instead ? maybe there is a better solution available.

Comment: I associate the term "stored procedure" with SQL and relational databases. You need to provide some context - what technologies are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the **[Saxon SQL extensions](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sql-extension/intro.xml)** can help?

Especially **[`<sql:execute>`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sql-extension/execute.xml)** ?